# Debugging web app in iPad Simulator

Tags: ipad, safari, ios-simulator, mobile-safari

I am developing a  web app for iPad and testing it on Safari on Mac and Safari on iPad Simulator. Now there are some issues with CSS in iPad Simulator which work quite well in Safari on Mac.
Now my question is,
 Is there a powerful debugging tool for Safari in iPad Simulator?

Comment: As of iOS 6 Remote Debugging is available: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12762449/72428

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Note**: As of iOS6 this is not the correct way of doing remote debugging, leaving this answer for  historical reasons but you should look into remote inspection with Safari, here is a good article: http://jeffreysambells.com/2012/09/22/ios-safari-web-inspector

Have a look at this, (a bash script I wrote) https://gist.github.com/2241976. It will allow you to open the iPad simulator and run Webkit's remote inspector, which will look just like this.

[image: iOS remote Inspector]

Comment: You should [disclose](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/130268) that this is your project.

Answer (score 29):

When running safari in an XCode device simulator, the desktop Safari (v6) Develop menu shows those devices.  From there, you can fire up the developer tools (DOM browser etc.) for the mobile browser.  This helped me debug an mobile safari css issue without hardware.

[image: iPad Simulator menu option]

Comment: Just to add to @t1m0 answer, you may need to turn the Develop menu on by going to Safari->Preferences->Advanced->and check "Show Develop menu in menu bar".

Answer (score 0):

[iWebInspector](http://www.iwebinspector.com/) is quite a powerful tool for the iOs simulator's Safari.
It uses the same inspector as Chrome and it works nicely (I've used it myself and found it really helpful).

From their website

> iWebInspector is a free tool to debug, profile and inspect web
>   applications running on iOS Simulator (iPhone or iPad). You can check
>   resources, see and change HTML & CSS, use breakpoints on JavaScript
>   code, create charts and more just as if you were on Safari for
>   Desktop, Chrome or Firebug.
>
> It works for any web in Safari -the web browser-, for a chrome-less
>   webapp (full-screen) and also for apps using UIWebView -including
>   PhoneGap applications-.