# Sencha touch iOS run shows black screen on simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I've created a simple sencha touch app to test on my iOS simulator, and when I run it I get a black screen on my simulator. Here are the steps I took:

1. `npm install -g cordova`
2. `sencha -sdk /path/to/SenchaTouch generate app MyApp /path/to/MyApp`
3. obtained a certificate, identify devices, and got an AppID.
4. `sencha cordova init com.example.TestApp TestApp`
5. Edited app.json and added: `"platforms": "ios”,`
6. `sencha app build -run native`

When I run `sencha App build -run native` I get the iOS simulator to come up and display nothing but a black screen and the safari app. However when I run the sencha cmd server and go to http://localhost:80/ to test my app it runs fine.

What am  I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Try to debug it using remote debugging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839743/debugging-web-app-in-ipad-simulator

Do you see any errors?

Comment: No I didn't get any errors, but eventuality found out how to run it on my actual device using xCode and now everything works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I eventually found out how to run it on my device using the xcode project that cordova built for me in its iOS folder.

Note: if I use xcode to run it on my emulator it also works now too, just didn't when I tried to run it with `sencha app run native`