# DOM inspector for safari in iPAD

Tags: ipad, dom, safari, web-inspector

I have to test my web application in iPAD. To do so, i want to inspect my elements, is there any way to inspect elements in iPAD using safari?

Comment: As of iOS 6 Remote Debugging is available: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12762449/72428

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, [weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre) (WEb INspector REmote) is what you're looking for.

If you want to test your webapp on a virtual iPad, then check out [iWebInspector](http://www.iwebinspector.com/).

Comment: The above link no longer works. The correct link is: http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/